# Returning multiple objects from a predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a basic Prolog fact base consisting of entrees, sides, and ingredients. I wish to write a predicate called `meal(X,Y)` that takes in either lunch/dinner for parameter x and returns the entree and both sides. i.e. `meal(lunch,X)` returns sandwich, chips, lemonade.

```
/* Facts */

entre(lunch, sandwich).
entre(dinner, spaghetti).

side(lunch, chips).
side(lunch, lemonade).
side(dinner, bread).
side(dinner, greentea).

ingredient(chips, potato).
ingredient(chips, salt).
ingredient(lemonade, lemon).
ingredient(lemonade, sugar).
ingredient(bread, egg).
ingredient(bead, flour).
ingredient(greentea, green).
ingredient(greentea, tea).

/* Rules */


meal(X,Y) :- entre(X,Y) ; side(X,Y).
```

I cannot get it to work, as it only returns

```
| ?- meal(lunch, X).

X = sandwich ?

yes
```

Comment: You should press `;` for the next element in your query (so after it says `X = sandwhich`).

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my issue.

Comment: Please keep in mind that prolog has predicates, not functions, and that something that "returns" a value could well also be the input or even an input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
meal(X,Y) :-
    findall(Z,(entre(X,Z);side(X,Z)),Y).
```